# Bullet Form Data For JSON to iOS

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm just curious if my way on how to construct my Firebase database is correct. I just wanna put a bullet form data (Features) in iOS app's view. Is this correct? I have a child node called **features** and this path has keys and values of each feature that this item has. Then I will proceed to print them in bullet form in iOS.

OR

Is there a better way? Maybe such as putting "\n" in my database?

I hope this isn't an absurd question. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This way is good because in the Swift code you are able to iterate through the list and display each in a bullet easily